# Is there a way to make sure results show on blade template?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to show a brewery's most popular products on each of their pages, however finding it difficult to come up with a solution to do so.

Here is what I have in my controller

```
$brewery = Brewery::find($id);

        $products = DB::table('order_details')
            ->select('product_name', DB::raw('COUNT(product_name) as orders'))
            ->groupBy('product_name')
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(product_name)'), 'DESC')
            ->take(4)
            ->get();

        return view("brewery", compact("brewery", "products"));
```

How can I make sure that it is just the specific brewery's most popular products and not the most popular products of all breweries?

Comment: Could you not just add a where clause your SQL statement? `->where('brewery_id', $id)`

Comment: You pull the `$brewery`, but then don't use it in the query.  If you have model relationships between Brewery and Product, it will give you the product just for that brewery - and can even use the built in Laravel query methods

Comment: brewery_id doesnt exist in that table, it is just the product name in the table "order_details", I was hoping there would be a way to do it without the query

Comment: you should have tables for breweries, orders and products. currently you are looking for most sold products. you should join the bewery on the products and then add the brewery as where-condition